# Merge, Rebase or Branch for a persistent branch?

Tags: git, github

Conceptually:
I have a branch off **master** called **'core'** .

This branch will exist forever.

Once a week **core** needs to  pick up any changes that have been made to **master**.

Once a month changes made in **core** need to be pushed back into **master**.

**core** will sometimes have branches like **feature1** or **feature2** that may exist for a month or two then they will be merged into **core** and the feature branch will be deleted then **core** will push those changes to **master** at a month end.

I could do this using rebase or merge or I could create a new **core** branch each month after it has been merged into **master**.

I think the best way to do this is to just use 'merge' weekly and monthly but I am not that knowledgeable about github so is this the correct way or do you foresee any problems down the road?

```
          week1    week2     month end
--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o master
  \        \         \         / \
   o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o---o--o--o--o core
          \              \             /
           o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o--o      feature
```

master is worked on by a large team, core has a small team and a feature will usually be one person (though still pushed to github for testing or demoing a feature), the core and master teams don't often touch the same files.

Comment: Asking if you should merge, rebase, or create a new branch is asking about things which aren't really in common.  You need to decide for yourself what workflow is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggested workflow is a bit similar to the [Git flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (see also [this cheatsheet](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)).

Regarding your question about merge vs. rebase, it should be noted that a `git rebase` is a destructive operation (not only it changes the SHA1 of the rebased commits, but it is possible that the code-base of each commit in the source branch does compile, while some or all of these commits do not compile anymore after the rebase!). In contrast, a `git merge` will preserve all commits from the two branches at stake, and create a merge commit, which could incorporate conflict resolution changes if need be.

This "drawback" of `git rebase` is probably the reason why in practice, the Git flow is always implemented using `git merge` (actually, `git merge --no-ff`, see the corresponding [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---no-ff)).

However, some teams may choose a different workflow for integrating contributions in master, requiring to use `git rebase origin/master` whenever there is some conflict between the feature branch and master (in order to have a more "beautiful", linear history). Still, in this case it is advised to check that each rebased commit still compiles (in order not to hinder [bisecting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect)).